# Part of JSON returned by API is serialised by JSON.NET but not all

Tags: c#, json.net, restsharp

I imagine this is more of a problem with my code rather than a problem with JSON.NET, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I have the following class below which is being used to serialise the json data found at this link: https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

To construct this class I used a JSON to C# generator found on google.

Also below are the methods I use to pull and serialise the JSON data into a WeatherData object.

```
private string GetJsonFromWeb(string resource, string city)
{
    var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.GET);
    request.AddParameter("q", city);
    request.AddParameter("APPID", "af5e6fd579e0ddb303afc1774487c77b");

    var fullUrl = client.BuildUri(request);
    Console.WriteLine("Full URL: " + fullUrl.AbsoluteUri);

    var response = client.Execute(request);
    string json = response.Content;
    return json;
}

private WeatherData SerializeJsonToWeatherData(string json)
{
    WeatherData weatherData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherData>(json);
    return weatherData;
}
```

These methods work successfully, as the JSON data can be used later in the application to display information within the GUI. However the MainData part of the JSON data is set to null after the JSON is pulled from the API.

```
class WeatherData
{
    public Coord Coord { get; set; }
    public List<Weather> Weather { get; set; }
    public string Base { get; set; }
    public MainData MainData { get; set; }
    public int Visibility { get; set; }
    public Wind Wind { get; set; }
    public Clouds Clouds { get; set; }
    public int Dt { get; set; }
    public Sys Sys { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Cod { get; set; }
}

public class Coord
{
    public double Lon { get; set; }
    public double Lat { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Main { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
}

public class MainData
{
    public double Temp { get; set; }
    public int Pressure { get; set; }
    public int Humidity { get; set; }
    public double Temp_min { get; set; }
    public double Temp_max { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public double Speed { get; set; }
    public int Deg { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int All { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Message { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int Sunrise { get; set; }
    public int Sunset { get; set; }
}
```

Sample JSON from above API

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": -0.13,
    "lat": 51.51
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 300,
      "main": "Drizzle",
      "description": "light intensity drizzle",
      "icon": "09d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 280.32,
    "pressure": 1012,
    "humidity": 81,
    "temp_min": 279.15,
    "temp_max": 281.15
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 4.1,
    "deg": 80
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 90
  },
  "dt": 1485789600,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5091,
    "message": 0.0103,
    "country": "GB",
    "sunrise": 1485762037,
    "sunset": 1485794875
  },
  "id": 2643743,
  "name": "London",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Comment: just change your `MainData` class name to only `Main`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON property is called `main` not `mainData`. JSON.Net can't find a property called `mainData` ans thus does not populate the `MainData` property of your POCOs